# open a folder to then use the files in python correctly

Tags: python

Usually I navigate to the folder I am extracting data from and copy the file name directly:

```
df2=pd.read_csv('10_90_bnOH-MEA.csv',usecols=[1])
```

If I have multiple files and want to do the same for all the files, how do I specify the folder to open and get all the files inside?

I want to run the above code without specifying the file's full path
(`C:\Users\X\Desktop\Y\Z\10_90_bnOH-MEA.csv`)

Comment: are you asking how to change python's working directory ([`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir))?

Answer (score 0):

You want listdir from the os module.

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\Y\\Z\\"
files = os.listdir(path)
print(files)

dataframe_list = []
for filename in files:
    dataframe_list.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,filename)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open the desired directory and loop through all the files then do something to them.

```py
# import required module
import os
# assign directory
directory = 'files'
 
# iterate over files in
def goThroughDirectory(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        # checking if it is a file
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            # do something
```

If you also want to loop through all the files in a directory you should add a check for `if os.path.isdir(f)` like this

```py
...

def goThroughDirectory(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        # checking if it is a file
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            # do something
        elif os.path.isdir(f):
            # its not a file but a directory then loop through that directory aswell
            goThroughDirectory(directory + "\" + f)
```

for more information you should check [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-using-python/)